# How to increment and decrement counter in angular 4

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

Can you please tell me how to increment and decrement counter in Angular 4?

I used `ngrx` for state management, but I am not able to increment and decrement value.

Here is my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8nsfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

```
incrementCounter() {
    this.store.dispatch(new IncrementCounter());
}

decrementCounter() {
    this.store.dispatch(new DecrementCounter());
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.counter =this.store.select('counterValue');
}
```

Comment: You have a Typo in your code: `new IncreamentCounter()` shouldn't this be `new IncrementCounter()`
Is this a copy+paste error or an error in your code?

Comment: can you please give your code

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q8nsfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Fcounter.action.ts

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
<div class="container">
  <button (click)="incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
  <button (click)="decrementCounter()">Decrement</button>
   {{(c | async | json)}}
</div>
ngOnInit(){
    this.c =this.store.select('counterValue');

  }
```

and see what happen: counter will become {counter:-1} or {counter:1}

So, change the code using a variable "contador"

```
<div class="container">
  <button (click)="incrementCounter()">Increment</button>
  <button (click)="decrementCounter()">Decrement</button>
   {{contador)}}
</div>
contador:number=0;
ngOnInit(){
  this.store.select('counterValue').subscribe(val=>{
      this.contador+=val.counter;
    });
}
```

Comment: I "rearranged" my answer